# Allow to not disclose employer names (and don't generate a page for them)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

We have the following companies already:

- [Various companies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/331647/various-companies?storyType=1)
- [Various](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/329531/various?storyType=1)
- [(Various)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/314918/various?storyType=1)
- [Various Companies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/312179/various-companies?storyType=1)

When adding a position, I would like to be able to select something like "Various companies" or "Don't wish to disclose", without that option generating a page for a company that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have always wondered if current employers are able to see the developer stories

Comment: What if some of them actually worked for [Various](http://www.various.com/)? How do we know? :P

Comment: @Laurel for that company an entry with page and logo already exists. ;)

Comment: Where did you find these links?

Comment: @Filip if you create a new position, select a company and save the position, you can click the company name.

Comment: So what is the use case of not disclosing hiring companies? The only use case would be external fee-based recruiters, and those are IIRC not allowed on SO careers anyways.

Comment: @Magisch I've had several contracts that prohibited me from disclosing my customers in public.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Well then you list the contracting firm as the offer company, no?

Comment: @Magisch it's hard to disclose a use case for something you do not wish to disclose. But take for example working for companies doing something that you aren't really proud of, or which is frowned upon. Say, porn, gambling or churning out clones of mobile games. It's fine if that is brought up in an intake, but not something people would want to display publicly.

Comment: @Magisch There is not always a contracting firm present. Its not that its OFTEN that I would need to hide the customer, but it is > 0.

Comment: we need ability to close company as a duplicate. Canonical dupe target for various "Various" will likely be Crossover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback.

The company name is an optional field when creating a new work item. We've now made this clearer by adding "(required)" labels to fields that are mandatory.

[image]

We're also looking into reducing he duplication of company names in the auto complete suggestion.